# How do I hide a list item when a span element is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, event-handling

What's the best way to hide a list item when a span inside the list item is clicked. I have included the code below. I'm trying to build a to-do list app and I'm stuck trying to write a script that removes/hide a task that has been done from the result list when the user clicks on the red "X" text.

```js
 
 var submitTask = $("#display-taskList");
 var taskList = $("#taskList");
 var submitTask = $("#submit-task");
 var list = "<li>" + inputTask + "</li>"
  var inputTask = $("#inputTask").val();

  submitTask.click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var inputTask = $("#inputTask").val();
  var list = "<li>" + inputTask + "</li>"

   if (inputTask === "") {
    alert("Add a task")
   }

   else{
    $("ol").append("<li>" + $("#inputTask").val() + "<span id='close'>" + "x" +"</span>" + "</li>" );
   }


 });

  function doneTask(){
   var x = $('#listResult');
  $(x).click(function(e) {
   if (e.target.tagName === 'SPAN'){
   var y =$("#close");
   var n = $(y).closest('li')
      return n.style.visibility = "hidden";
  };
  });
 }

 doneTask();
```

```css
 html,body { height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; }
  body{
   background: #F3904F; /* fallback for old browsers */
   background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to left, #F3904F , #3B4371); /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
   background: linear-gradient(to left, #F3904F , #3B4371); /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
        
  }

  #center-block {
      width:600px;
      height: 100%;
      padding:10px;
      background: #F3904F; /* fallback for old browsers */
   background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to left, #F3904F , #3B4371); /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
   background: linear-gradient(to left, #F3904F , #3B4371); /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
  }

  #inputTask{
  width: 530px;
  height: 44px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  font: 16px arial,sans-serif;
     line-height: 34px;
     height: 34px !important;
     margin-top: 20px;
     margin-bottom: 25px
     ;
  }

  input[type=text]{
   background-color: #3B4371;
   font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
  }

  input[type=text]:focus {
     background-color: #fff;
     font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
     box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
     border: 3px solid #555;: 
  }

  #title{
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  }

  hr{
   width: 50;
  }

  button{
  margin-top: 10px;
  opacity: 0.5;
  cursor: default;
     font-family: arial,sans-serif;
     font-size: 15px;
     font-weight: bold;
     margin: 5px 30px 10px 30px;
     min-width: 54px;
     height: 30px;
     padding: 0 16px;
     text-align: center;
  }

  ol > li {
   color: #fff;
   font-family: sans-serif;
   font-size: 20px;
   background-color: #A9A9A9;
   margin-top: 5px;
   padding-left: 5px;
  }
  
  
  li:hover{
   background: #808080;
   cursor: pointer;
  }

  .strike{
   text-decoration: line-through;
  }

  #close{
   color: red;
   font-size: 30px;
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div class="container" id="center-block">
<div class="row">
 <form>
  <h1 class="text-center" id="title">Simple to-Do list</h1>
  <hr width="50%">
  <input type="text" id="inputTask" name="" placeholder="Title...">
  <button id="submit-task">Hit Me!</button>
  <!-- <button id="submit-task">Clear List</button> -->
 
 
 <div id="display-taskList">
  <h3 style="color: #fff; font-family: 'Kanit';"> Task to accomplish</h3> 
  <ol id="listResult"></ol>
  </div>
     </form> 
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Just to solve you're issue. [`closest`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) function returns an array. Hence `return n.style.visibility = "hidden"` will be invalid because the `n` here is an array & not an object. Use `return n[0].style.visibility = "hidden"` instead to hide the item. That being said - there are much better ways to approach this problem. You can follow any one of them given below by my friends.

Comment: thanks @NikhilNanjappa I think your have the best explanation. i really understand what I wrote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good approach to this problem would be binding a `click` event to every `span` element. If user clicks it, then the parent of the clicked `span` element is hidden.

**Edit**: If you click and add new `todo`, the input is cleared immediately.

```js
var submitTask = $("#display-taskList");
var taskList = $("#taskList");
var submitTask = $("#submit-task");
var list = "<li>" + inputTask + "</li>"
var inputTask = $("#inputTask").val();

submitTask.click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var inputTask = $("#inputTask").val();
  var list = "<li>" + inputTask + "</li>"

  if (inputTask === "") {
    alert("Add a task")
  } else {
    $("ol").append("<li>" + $("#inputTask").val() + "<span id='close'>" + "x" + "</span>" + "</li>");
    $('#inputTask').val(null);
  }

  $('#listResult').find('span').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().hide();
  });

});
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

body {
  background: #F3904F;
  /* fallback for old browsers */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to left, #F3904F, #3B4371);
  /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(to left, #F3904F, #3B4371);
  /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
}

#center-block {
  width: 600px;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #F3904F;
  /* fallback for old browsers */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to left, #F3904F, #3B4371);
  /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(to left, #F3904F, #3B4371);
  /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
}

#inputTask {
  width: 530px;
  height: 44px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  font: 16px arial, sans-serif;
  line-height: 34px;
  height: 34px !important;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

input[type=text] {
  background-color: #3B4371;
  font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
}

input[type=text]:focus {
  background-color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  border: 3px solid #555;
  :
}

#title {
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}

hr {
  width: 50;
}

button {
  margin-top: 10px;
  opacity: 0.5;
  cursor: default;
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 5px 30px 10px 30px;
  min-width: 54px;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 0 16px;
  text-align: center;
}

ol>li {
  color: #fff;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  background-color: #A9A9A9;
  margin-top: 5px;
  padding-left: 5px;
}

li:hover {
  background: #808080;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.strike {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}

#close {
  color: red;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class="container" id="center-block">
    <div class="row">
      <form>
        <h1 class="text-center" id="title">Simple to-Do list</h1>
        <hr width="50%">
        <input type="text" id="inputTask" name="" placeholder="Title...">
        <button id="submit-task">Hit Me!</button>
        <!-- <button id="submit-task">Clear List</button> -->


        <div id="display-taskList">
          <h3 style="color: #fff; font-family: 'Kanit';"> Task to accomplish</h3>
          <ol id="listResult"></ol>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: it works! and thanks for the improvement, I mean the clear input feature..

Comment: @SopeIsaacOrija My pleasure. If you want you can upvote my answer :)

Comment: @SopeIsaacOrija You marked the question as the best one, but you didn't upvote :D

Comment: Sorry I just figured out to do that. I've upvoted it

Comment: @SopeIsaacOrija Thanks xd

Answer (score 0):

You can use following approaches:

- Use jquery .hide() method. 
   n.hide();
- Use jquery .css( "display", "none" ) method
   n.css( "display", "none" )

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a class in the span.

```
<span class="revovable">

$('.removable').on('click', function(){
    $(this).hide();
    //if you want to remove the element you can use this
    $(this).remove();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use Jquery css not style. It allows you to set properties like `.css('key', 'value')`

In this case I set `.css('display', 'none')`

```js
 
 var submitTask = $("#display-taskList");
 var taskList = $("#taskList");
 var submitTask = $("#submit-task");
 var list = "<li>" + inputTask + "</li>"
  var inputTask = $("#inputTask").val();

  submitTask.click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var inputTask = $("#inputTask").val();
  var list = "<li>" + inputTask + "</li>"

   if (inputTask === "") {
    alert("Add a task")
   }

   else{
    $("ol").append("<li>" + $("#inputTask").val() + "<span id='close'>" + "x" +"</span>" + "</li>" );
   }


 });

  function doneTask(){
   var x = $('#listResult');
  $(x).click(function(e) {
   if (e.target.tagName === 'SPAN'){
      $(e.target).closest('li').css('display', 'none');
  };
  });
 }

 doneTask();
```

```css
 html,body { height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; }
  body{
   background: #F3904F; /* fallback for old browsers */
   background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to left, #F3904F , #3B4371); /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
   background: linear-gradient(to left, #F3904F , #3B4371); /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
        
  }

  #center-block {
      width:600px;
      height: 100%;
      padding:10px;
      background: #F3904F; /* fallback for old browsers */
   background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to left, #F3904F , #3B4371); /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
   background: linear-gradient(to left, #F3904F , #3B4371); /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
  }

  #inputTask{
  width: 530px;
  height: 44px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  font: 16px arial,sans-serif;
     line-height: 34px;
     height: 34px !important;
     margin-top: 20px;
     margin-bottom: 25px
     ;
  }

  input[type=text]{
   background-color: #3B4371;
   font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
  }

  input[type=text]:focus {
     background-color: #fff;
     font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
     box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
     border: 3px solid #555;: 
  }

  #title{
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  }

  hr{
   width: 50;
  }

  button{
  margin-top: 10px;
  opacity: 0.5;
  cursor: default;
     font-family: arial,sans-serif;
     font-size: 15px;
     font-weight: bold;
     margin: 5px 30px 10px 30px;
     min-width: 54px;
     height: 30px;
     padding: 0 16px;
     text-align: center;
  }

  ol > li {
   color: #fff;
   font-family: sans-serif;
   font-size: 20px;
   background-color: #A9A9A9;
   margin-top: 5px;
   padding-left: 5px;
  }
  
  
  li:hover{
   background: #808080;
   cursor: pointer;
  }

  .strike{
   text-decoration: line-through;
  }

  #close{
   color: red;
   font-size: 30px;
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div class="container" id="center-block">
<div class="row">
 <form>
  <h1 class="text-center" id="title">Simple to-Do list</h1>
  <hr width="50%">
  <input type="text" id="inputTask" name="" placeholder="Title...">
  <button id="submit-task">Hit Me!</button>
  <!-- <button id="submit-task">Clear List</button> -->
 
 
 <div id="display-taskList">
  <h3 style="color: #fff; font-family: 'Kanit';"> Task to accomplish</h3> 
  <ol id="listResult"></ol>
  </div>
     </form> 
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks @carlo. This works too. However now I want to add a strike through  style on the list item. Can I do this using the same method?

Comment: You can. Just set the text-decoration to line-through.

Comment: Hi @carlos I did that but now it's affecting the "X" too.

`function strike(){
 var x = $("#listResult");
 $(x).click(function(event) {
 if(event.target.tagName === "LI"){
  $(event.target).css("text-decoration", "line-through");
  }
});

 } `

Comment: Then either apply the `.strike` class you have already defined in your css, and then for that class exclude the span. Or better yet, give your content a class too, so something like `value`. Then that can be styled on it's own.

Comment: This still didnt work. I have create a class called checked. and it still didnt work.
`function strike(){
 var x = $("#listResult");
 $(x).click(function(event) {
  if(event.target.tagName === "LI"){
  $(event.target).closest('li').addClass('checked');
  }
 });

 } 
strike() `